# Kubernetes internal load balancer on gcloud

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, internal-load-balancer

I might ask a wrong question here, but i am trying create an internal load balancer like this

i have an API service that is accessible by `http://[api_service_name]:3000` and a simple nginx gateway service that proxy_pass `http://[gateway_service_name]:80` to `http://[api_service_name]:3000`

my API service service.yaml file is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    service: api-service-name
  name: api-service-name
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3000"
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    service: api-service-name
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

and my API service deployment.yaml file is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: api-service-name
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        service: api-service-name
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        ...
        image: ...
        name: api-service-name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

while my nginx service.yaml is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    service: gateway-service-name
  name: gateway-service-name
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    service: gateway-service-name
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalName: gateway-service-name
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

and deployment.yaml is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: gateway-service-name
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        service: gateway-service-name
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ...
        name: gateway-service-name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

these settings work well for external loadbalancer/gateway. when i do `kubectl get svc` it prints

```
NAME                  CLUSTER-IP                EXTERNAL-IP      
gateway-service-name  gateway.int.ip.add.ress   gateway.ext.ip.add.ress
api-service-name      api.int.ip.add.ress       <none>
```

and i can browse through `http://gateway.ext.ip.add.ress/any_available_endpoints` just fine

i am trying to figure out if i can achieve the same thing without having to have an external ip address for my gateway, and use `http://gateway.int.ip.add.ress/any_available_endpoints` instead

i tried using the default `ClusterIp` `ServiceType` but its not working

NOTE: i will be accessing the network through a vpn and that another service that sits on another cluster will access this internally

UPDATE: i ended up putting my client (web) inside the same cluster, this way my gateway doesn't have to have an external ip address, i am not sure if this is the right approach but will keep it like this for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ClusterIP` `Service` is only accessible from other services in the same cluster so if your service is in ClusterA and your VPN is in ClusterB, the VPN won't be able to reach it as a `ClusterIP` `Service`.

One option is to continue to use a public IP with the `LoadBalancer` `Service` and configure the firewall to restrict traffic to only originating from your VPN using the `loadBalancerSourceRanges` setting on the `Service` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/)

If both ClusterA and ClusterB are on the same network (which is the default setting for new clusters), another option you have is to use `type: NodePort` for your `Service`. This will expose the service on a static port of each Node in ClusterA without opening any ports in the default firewall.

If ClusterA has nodes with IPs 10.128.0.2, 10.128.0.3, and 10.128.0.4, and you configure your `Service` like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    service: gateway-service-name
  name: gateway-service-name
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    nodePort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    service: gateway-service-name
  type: NodePort
  externalName: gateway-service-name
```

then you should be able to connect to your service at `http://10.128.0.2/any_available_endpoints` or `http://10.128.0.3/any_available_endpoints` or `http://10.128.0.4/any_available_endpoints`

Comment: i did a quick try using your suggestion, i got this error `spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 80: provided port is not in the valid range. The range of valid ports is 30000-32767`, i googled about this and i bumped into https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11690#issuecomment-123987672 which i think it says that we shouldn't set this statically to avoid conflict? and by node IPs, do you mean my service clusterIP or my pods ip? so i tried removing `nodePort` and apply the changes and then  i tried both IPs, but still doesnt work

Comment: i ended up putting my client inside the same cluster, this way my gateway doesnt have to have an external ip address, i am not sure if this is the right approach but will keep it like this for now